# Read a json file and save the data (as json) in list

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I'm trying to read data from a file and save it in list so that I can retrieve it later. Something like:

#### sample.json

```
{
  "circles": [
    {"x":14,"y":2,"z":4,"r":50},
    {"x":14,"y":2,"z":4,"r":50}
  ]
}
```

What I am looking for is:

```
var circle_list = []
circle_lst = some_function_which_reads_json_from_file('sample.json')
//Now circle list contains
circle_list = [
  {"x":14,"y":2,"z":4,"r":50},
  {"x":14,"y":2,"z":4,"r":50}
]
```

Later I can just do something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i <circle_list.lenght;i++){
  //do osmething
}
```

I was looking into

```
$.getJSON("sample.json" , function(data){
  //
});
```

But then I came to know this call is asynchronous... But I need to maintain execution order.

Answer (score 2):

Don't maintain execution order.  This will lock up the browser during the fetching.  Use this only as an absolute last resort:

```
var circle_list;
$.ajax({'dataType': 'json', url: 'sample.json', 'async': false})
    .done(function(json) {
        circle_list = json;
});
```

Instead, you can do at least a couple of other things:

1. Work with callback.  It doesn't have to all be in one spot thanks to deferreds.
2. Load the JSON along with the rest of the page and fetch it from the DOM.

Comment: I am getting this error
....ajax({'dataType': 'json', 'sample.json', 'async': false}).done(function(json) 

garbage.html (line 65, col 45)

Comment: yntaxError: missing : after property id.. and it points to somewhere in "sample.json" comma

Comment: @user2052251 edited; you should really learn to debug simple problems on your own